# Can I use Apple Pay in the US with an Australian AMEX?

Tags: internationalization, apple-pay

I'm travelling from Australia to the US. Apple Pay isn't available in Australia yet.

My question is: **Can I use Apple Pay in the US with an Australian AMEX?**

Comment: AFIK-At this time the Apple Pay only accepts credit cards that are issued in the USA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No, you can't.

Long answer: Apple Pay is, officially, US-only right now. However, it is possible to [use Apple Pay in Australia](https://beaugil.es/2014/10/apple-pay-works-in-australia/):

> To show the Apple Pay settings, simply open the Settings app on your iPhone (or iPad mini 3 or iPad Air 2), tap on General, Tap on Language & Region, and tap on ‘Region’. Change it to the United States.

However, there is a big caveat:

> While you can go through the setup process, your card must be issued by a participating bank before it can be used with Apple Pay. If you try to add a card from a bank that isn’t yet supported (i.e a card from, or issued in Australia), you’ll simply receive an error.

The Apple support article [Apple Pay participating issuers](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT6288) lists the currently-supported banks.

So, while you could use it in Australia with a US-issued card, the reverse is not possible.